# QGIS Least Cost Paths with multiple start and end points

Tags: qgis, cost-path

I have a raster of UK rivers and I have a points layer of various spots within that raster. I was to compute least cost paths between each point. I've tried the [Least-Cost Path plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/leastcostpath/), but it is taking a lot of computational time and memory for only a subset of the data. It also only takes one start node. Are there any plugins methods that are good at handling large rasters and thousands of start/ end nodes.

Ultimately, I want to calculate corridor paths along the rivers and identify pinch points to dispersal.

Comment: As far as I know, LCP agorithms only allow you to take one end point at a time (many starting points, tho), as the cost layer is different for each point. So you have to make it recursively, point by point. But you can automatize that in the graphical modeler.